# Logging in Databricks/Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am quite new to spark/databricks and I know that there is a logging in Azure.
My idea is to have a log like a print, directly in the databricks notebook. Somebody said to me to use the native spark lib, but I could´t find anything anywhere about that.

Thank you and sorry :)

EDIT:
I tried doing this log in a notebook in databricks with Python:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.warning("This is a warning message") #it prints to the notebook
logger.error("This is an error message") #this also prints to the notebook, but the following don't print to the notebook:
logger.debug("About to do something")
logger.info("This is an informational message")
```

I wanted to know something like this, but this is from Python, and I wanted to know if there is a logging behaving like a print lib in Spark, something like this:

```py
import loging_from_Spark_lib
logger("The process 1 is starting...")
```

and it prints the message: "The process 1 is starting..." to the notebook.

I don't know if there is a native library from Spark, my boss asked me that and I could't find it. Plus if there isn't is there a better way of doing this in databricks?
Once again Thanks :)

Comment: Anything you tried. If yes, add those details in the question.

Comment: What's wrong with using the logging module?

Comment: @user2704177 when I do logging.info(…) it doesn’t appear on the notebook :/ just the .warning/.error and I just wanted logs for information like “Process starting”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even, I got same in my environment.

[image]

This is because of `Log Levels`.

According to the levels in [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) documentation the messages will be logged.
Default it will be `Warning`, below levels are not logged.
So, set the log level which ever you want and log.

Try below code block.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.warning("This is a warning message")
logger.error("This is an error message")
logger.debug("About to do something")
logger.info("This is an informational message")
```

[image]

Comment: that worked!! thank you so much!! :D i just have a little follow up question, is there a way of removing the _ _main_ _? thank you! :)

Comment: Yeah. Instead of giving `__name__` inside getlogger give your custom name.

Comment: Extra info: If you modulise your stuff and import them using python import, its relevant how you import them (if you use `logging.getLogger(__ name __)` in the modules. If you imort them with their full path from the root, that will be their name. But if you do a relative import, then only the filename will be the name. This affects the name of the logger, which again influences how you can set the loglevel from the main notebook.